# How to fill path item with color

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to draw closed path and fill it with some collor. Here the code

```
startRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits

startTypeUnits = app.preferences.typeUnits

startDisplayDialogs = app.displayDialogs



//change settings

app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS

app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS

app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO



var AD = activeDocument;



var bBox = new Array();

bBox[0] = 10;

bBox[1] = 10;



bBox[2] = 50;

bBox[3] = 10;



bBox[4] = 50;

bBox[5] = 50;



bBox[6] = 10;

bBox[7] = 50;



var line = new Array();

line[0] = new PathPointInfo;

line[0].kind = PointKind.CORNERPOINT;

line[0].anchor = [bBox[0],bBox[1]];

line[0].leftDirection = line[0].anchor;

line[0].rightDirection = line[0].anchor;



line[1] = new PathPointInfo;

line[1].kind = PointKind.CORNERPOINT;

line[1].anchor = [bBox[2],bBox[3]];

line[1].leftDirection = line[1].anchor;

line[1].rightDirection = line[1].anchor;



line[2] = new PathPointInfo;

line[2].kind = PointKind.CORNERPOINT;

line[2].anchor = [bBox[4],bBox[5]];

line[2].leftDirection = line[2].anchor;

line[2].rightDirection = line[2].anchor;



line[3] = new PathPointInfo;

line[3].kind = PointKind.CORNERPOINT;

line[3].anchor = [bBox[6],bBox[7]];

line[3].leftDirection = line[3].anchor;

line[3].rightDirection = line[3].anchor;



var lineSubPath= new Array();

lineSubPath[0] = new SubPathInfo();

lineSubPath[0].operation = ShapeOperation.SHAPEXOR;

lineSubPath[0].closed = true;

lineSubPath[0].entireSubPath = line;



var path = AD.pathItems.add("A", lineSubPath);



//var paperShape = AD.artLayers.add();



var colorRef = new SolidColor;

colorRef.rgb.red = 255

colorRef.rgb.green = 100;

colorRef.rgb.blue = 10;







path.fillPath(colorRef, ColorBlendMode.COLOR,100,true,0,true,true);



//shapeLayer.applyStyle("ransom_note");*/



app.preferences.rulerunits = startRulerUnits

app.preferences.typeunits = startTypeUnits

app.displayDialogs = startDisplayDialogs
```

path is drawn, but error apears while filling

**fillPath is not a function.**

Can anybody help?

P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` is a property of `Application`, Photoshop does not understand when you try to apply `fillPath` to it, even if you had declared it as a variable name... you just gets Photoshop confused on what to do.

You should simply change that's variable name to something like `myPath` and then `myPath.fillPath(colorRef, ColorBlendMode.COLOR,100,true,0,true,true);` will work.

I would also make a little change in the `ColorBlendMode`, if you set it to `COLOR` you won't be able to actually see the color you are applying, and it will seem that the script is not working at all.

Try `myPath.fillPath(colorRef, ColorBlendMode.NORMAL,100,true,0,true,true);` and you're done!